# Es aconsejable utilizar varios render controllers en una vista?

Tags: symfony2

Tengo una vista que representa un dashboard, en la misma incluyo varios paneles con datos calculables dinámicamente, para mostrar cada panel empleo el método render(controller(...)). Es aconsejable hacerlo de esta manera, o calcular todos los datos en el controlador de la vista ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque podría interpretarse como una respuesta basada en opiniones, el hecho es que el propio [manual oficial de symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html) aconseja su uso.

> Whenever you find that you need a variable or a piece of information that you don't have access to in a template, consider rendering a controller. Controllers are fast to execute and promote good code organization and reuse. Of course, like all controllers, they should ideally be "skinny", meaning that as much code as possible lives in reusable services.

Que viene a significar

> Siempre que encuentres que necesitas una variable o una pieza de información a la que no tienes acceso desde una plantilla, considera la posibilidad de procesar un controlador. Los controladores son rápidos de ejecutar y promueven la organización de buen código y su reutilización. Por supuesto, al igual que todos los controladores, idealmente deberían ser "de un tamaño reducido", lo que significa que tanto código como sea posible debería alojarse en servicios reutilizables.

Dicho esto, es totalmente lógico y de uso extendido crear métodos en controladores para generar trozos de código cuando estos se van a ser usados en varios sitios de tu aplicación.

Pero si por el contrario, solo vas a mostrarlos en el "dashboard" de tu aplicación, quizás sea más sencillo que cargues todos los valores en desde el controlador, y organices cada bloque en plantillas haciendo uso de ella mediante bloques de tipo `include`

Comment: analizando tu explicación pues me conviene que sean controladores includios en la plantilla, ya que varios de los datos pues dependen de variables pasadas desde la vista en dependencia de un nivel estructural seleccionado por el usuario, y aunque de manera general los paneles del dash lucen "iguales" si existe diferencia a la hora de generar el contenido. Gracias, me sirvió tu explicación.